# Using Range(Cell1 value, Cell2 value) - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell

I'm trying to define a range by the contents of two different cells, each containing the indirect cell addresses. I'm not sure whether it's possible, but here's an example:

- Cell `X100` contains value `$A$1`
- Cell `Y200` contains values `$C$5`

Is there any way I can use `Range()` and cells `X100` and `Y200` to arrive at `Range("$A$1:$C$5")`?

I've tried using Cells.Address but I can't figure out the right format for the application. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

**Edit**

Thank you Tom! I have another question for you. The X100 cell is actually variable in my case, and I was using the following formula to find it:

```
Cells.Find("ID").Offset(1,0).Address
```

Is there any way to incorporate this sort of formula into the Range application? Or would it be easier to define a static cell in the spreadsheet containing this formula?

Thanks a bunch

**Edit 2**

Here you are! I'm dimming r and x as ranges and setting them as follows:

```
r = Cells.Find("ID").Offset(1,0).Address

x = Cells.Find("Description of initiative").offset(1,0).end(xldown).Offset(0,cells.Find("ID").Column-cells.Find("Description of initiative").Column).address
```

They're convoluted I know, but I printed them out and they are returning the right cells in the $A$1 format.

Hope this clarifies! Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Don't use the address of the found cell. `Dim r as Range`, then `Set r = Cells.Find("ID").Offset(1)`. Now `r` is the range  you want (as long as the find is successful).

Comment: I've tried that, but how do I write it out as a Range()? I tried Range(r&":"&x) and Range(r,x) but neither work.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with how you're getting `r` and `x`?

Comment: Absolutely! Sorry for the delay, I'll do that right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than working with addresses, work with `Range` objects.

Not sure I fully understand your setup, but something like this is maybe what you're looking for.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim startCell As Range
    Set startCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="ID") '<--- you should specify the other parameters of Find

    Dim endCell As Range
    Set endCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="Description of initiative") '<--- again, specify parameters of Find

    If startCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<--- Find was unsuccessful
    If endCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<--- Find was unsuccessful

    Set startCell = startCell.Offset(1, 0)

    Dim columnOffset As Long
    columnOffset = startCell.Column - endCell.Column

    Set endCell = endCell.Offset(1).End(xlDown)
    Set endCell = endCell.Offset(, columnOffset) '<--- there's a simpler way to do this, this just gets you back to startCell.Column, but preserving your logic

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = ws.Range(startCell, endCell)

End Sub
```

Here's the simpler way to get `endCell` instead of the offset.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim startCell As Range
    Set startCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="ID") '<--- you should specify the other parameters of Find

    Dim endCell As Range
    Set endCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="Description of initiative") '<--- again, specify parameters of Find

    If startCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<--- Find was unsuccessful
    If endCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<--- Find was unsuccessful

    Set startCell = startCell.Offset(1, 0)

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = endCell.Offset(1).End(xlDown).Row
    Set endCell = ws.Cells(lastRow, startCell.Column)

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = ws.Range(startCell, endCell)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean

```
Range(Range("X100").Value2 & ":" & Range("Y200").Value2)
```

Comment: Yes! Ok that makes sense. One more for you if you don't mind!